# How can I add some values into my database

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

I'm a beginner in C# and I wrote a code that connect to my database but It give me a error

I did everything from first but nothing happened

```
private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
     string conString = "data source=DESKTOP-D5VFL9P; initial catalog = university; integrated security = True; MultipleActiveResultSets = True;";

     using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(conString)) 
     {
         connection.Open();

         using(SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Persons (PersonID, LastName, FirstName, Age, City) VALUES (" + int.Parse(txtPersonID.Text) + ", '" +
    txtLastName.Text + "', '" + txtFirstName.Text + "' ," + int.Parse(txtAge.Text) + ", '" + txtCity.Text + "'", connection)) 
         {
             using(SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader()) 
             {
                  MessageBox.Show("Data inserted");

                  txtFirstName.Text = "";
                  txtLastName.Text = "";
                  txtPersonID.Text = "";
                  txtAge.Text = "";
                  txtCity.Text = "";
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

I want to add some values to my database

Comment: I don’t know what’s wrong, but if you add details about your error message it might help others to answer your question.

Comment: Maybe, maybe if you use `command.ExecuteNonQuery()` instead of `command.ExecuteReader()`, you'll get the result that you desire!

Comment: What is an exception?

Comment: **[LITTLE BOBBY TABLES ALERT!](http://bobby-tables.com/)**

Comment: `.ExecuteReader()` will return a `SqlDataReader` to actually **read** some data from the database - this is completely wrong for **inserting** data - use `command.ExecuteNonQuery()` instead to execute any SQL statement that doesn't read data - `INSERT`, `UPDATE` or `DELETE`. Any beginner ADO.NET tutorial should surely have tought you that .....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be a `)` behind the City. Like `txtCity.Text + "')"`.

Comment: It seems like comment

Comment: "You must have 50 reputation to comment" ... i only have 7

Comment: Now 17 you have i think but you can explain your answer in a more good way

Comment: Although this does solve an issue, it doesn't stop injection; you would be far better off providing details on how to parametrise the query. It also will fail if you have a city with an apostrophe in it; for example Bishop's Stortford.

Answer (score 1):

**I am not recommending this** as it is definitely opens a door for [SQL Injection Attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) but Use below string that will work in your case:

```
string cmdText =  "INSERT INTO Persons(PersonID,LastName,FirstName,Age,City)" +
                     " VALUES ('" + int.Parse(txtPersonID.Text) + "', " +
                               "'" + txtLastName.Text + "', " +
                               "'" + txtFirstName.Text + "' ,'" +
                               int.Parse(txtAge.Text) + "', '" +
                               txtCity.Text + "')"
```

I would do something like this:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(conString))
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = 
        "INSERT INTO Persons (PersonID,LastName,FirstName,Age,City) VALUES (@PersonID,@LastName,@FirstName,@Age,@City)";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PersonID", int.Parse(txtPersonID.Text));
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", txtLastName.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", txtFirstName.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Age", int.Parse(txtAge.Text));
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", txtCity.Text);
    cmd.Connection = conn;
    conn.Open();
    int rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    if(rowsAffected > 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Data inserted");
    }
    else
    {
       MessageBox.Show("Failed");
    }
    conn.Close();
}
```