# Refresh database after execute a query and execute another query

Tags: c#, sql-server

***answer***

it was a mistake clear textBox before end of reading it .

thanks to @muhammad-azim

***End answer***

I have 2 insert in database first, second one has a foreign key to the first one. 
I get an error when executing the second `INSERT`:

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint

This part got error

Code:

```
SqlConnection con1 = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(cmdString, con1);
con1.Open();

cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery(); // insert(987,10000,2019-07-27 12:00:00 AM)
con1.Close();

// Some Code

SqlConnection con2 = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(cmdString2, con2);
con2.Open()

cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();//want insert(1,987,2000,2019-07-28 12:00:00 AM) but Got error
con2.Close();
```

Both of the queries are `INSERT`

I think Connection don't understand DB updated and got this error. 
when i stop app and run another time second query alone it work (that not worked before)

***All Code***

```
        PersianCalendar pc = new PersianCalendar();
        string[] dateInfo = txtcreteDate.Text.Split('-');
        DateTime createDate = new DateTime(Convert.ToInt32(dateInfo[0]), Convert.ToInt32(dateInfo[1]), Convert.ToInt32(dateInfo[2]), pc);

        int companyid = 1;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Factors (compId,createDate, code, duration, value," +
            " discount , payType , payTypeInfo , status)" +
            "VALUES " +
            " (@compId,@createDate, @code, @duration, @value, @discount , @payType , @payTypeInfo , 1) ", con);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@compId", companyid);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@createDate", createDate);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@code", txtCode.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@duration", Convert.ToInt32(txtDuration.Text));
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@value", Convert.ToDecimal(txtValue.Text));
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@discount", Convert.ToDecimal(txtDiscount.Text));
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@payType", companyid);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@payTypeInfo", companyid);

        con.Open();
        try
        {
            var insertedItem = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch(Exception ez)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("شماره فاکتور تکراری است");
            return;
        }
        ClearTextBoxes();
        if (comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() == "نقد" && insertedItem >0)
        {
            for (int counter1 = 0; counter1 < cashDataGridView.Rows.Count; counter1++)
            {
                string status = "پرداخت نشده";
                PersianCalendar pc1 = new PersianCalendar();
                string[] dateInfoPay = cashDataGridView.Rows[counter1].Cells["date"].Value.ToString().Split('-');
                DateTime PayDate = new DateTime(Convert.ToInt32(dateInfoPay[0]), Convert.ToInt32(dateInfoPay[1]), Convert.ToInt32(dateInfoPay[2]), pc1);
                //System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection con1 = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(connectionString);
                string cmdString = "INSERT INTO Payout (value,date,status,description,fid)";
                cmdString += " VALUES ";
                cmdString += " ( '" + Convert.ToDecimal(cashDataGridView.Rows[counter1].Cells["value"].Value.ToString()).ToString() + "' ,";
                cmdString += " '" + PayDate.ToString() + "' , ";
                cmdString += " '" + status.ToString() + "' , ";
                cmdString += " '" + status.ToString() + "' , ";
                cmdString += " '" + txtCode.Text + "' )";
                System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand cmd1 = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(cmdString, con);
                MessageBox.Show(cmd1.CommandText.ToString());
                cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery(); // i got error here

            }
            con.Close();
```

Comment: Too few details provided. But first, use `using` around `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` instances. Secondly, it will depend on your data. Check the database between the two inserts. And check the inserts precisely too, even with the Profiler. And third, DRY!

Comment: i have no problem with using . `FOREIGN Constraint` cause Error . it stop insert in table to becuse there is no such `key` in table 1 . but i already inserted this in `cmd1`

Comment: Note that the `visual-studio` tag is intended for questions relating to the Visual Studio application, not code you write with it.

Comment: You seem to be sure about this, but have you *checked*? Remember: we dont se your screen!

Comment: i stop run and check db and comment first query and do second one alone . it work

Comment: Add `using` where needed. Not closing the connection properly might affect the implicit transaction.

Comment: @John thanks for Edit and i remember it . but don't understand why u vote for close . if something is wrong about question let me know

Comment: I haven't voted to close your question, but I will say that it looks like it's missing sufficient information to constitute a [mcve], so we can't reproduce your issue. Ideally we would have your table definitions and relationships, and the queries that you are running. Oh, and some sample data.

Comment: ok i will edit it soon . thanks

Comment: @ZorgoZ the `Open` and `Close` connection is ok, all `using` cluase do, is `try{}-catch{}-finally{//dispose of object}`, the using will save him the need to use `Close` but nothing more.

Comment: @NozarSafari Could you please share the full error information ?

Comment: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Payout_Facotrd". The conflict occurred in database "C:\USERS\User\DOCUMENTS\VISUAL STUDIO 2017\PROJECTS\EXCEL\EXCEL\DB.MDF", table "dbo.Factors", column 'code'.

Comment: @NozarSafari For test purpose, is this possible to remove the foreign key relationship from Payout Table. If possible remove the foreign key relationship and do some insertion operation & observe the data carefully.

Comment: i already do it and it work , both table have right data. it fix problem, but not the right way.

Comment: @NozarSafari  ClearTextBoxes(); does this clear the value of txtCode.Text ?

Comment: yes it a Function that clear my form. nothing important

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185776/discussion-between-muhammad-azim-and-nozar-safari).

Comment: @NozarSafari Check this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53922016/how-can-i-add-some-values-into-my-database/53922835#53922835

Comment: tnx i do this fix , tnx for comment

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem here:

```
SqlConnection con1 = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(cmdString, con1);
con1.Open();
cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
con1.Close();
```

`ExecuteNonQuery()` returns the number of rows affected, if no rows affected, the return value is `-1` and a rollback to the operation occurs.

In order to make sure the insert succeeded and both of the operations completed successfully you should always use vlidations:

```
try
{
  SqlConnection con1 = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
  SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(cmdString, con1);
  con1.Open();
  var rowsAffected = cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
  con1.Close();
  //Some Code
  if(rowsAffected > 0)
  {
    SqlConnection con2 = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(cmdString2, con2);
    con2.Open()
    cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con2.Close();
  }
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
  //handle error in insert
}
```

Please refer also to [SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() returns -1 when doing Insert / Update / Delete](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/spike/2009/01/27/sqlcommand-executenonquery-returns-1-when-doing-insert-update-delete/)

Comment: i check it . it return `1` but second query dosent work . until i close and open app .

Comment: @ZorgoZ i dont understand what you say can explain more? u mean i delet `using` and define it in line ?

Comment: No. `using` is the way. When debugging, dont stop it, only pause (with a breakpoint) before the second insert. Then check the db. And start the profiler to see what exactly is happening. But without a schema and sample data, this could be anything..

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use two connection objects.

```
 using(SqlConnection con1 = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
 {
  using(SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(cmdString, con1))
   {
    con1.Open();

    //ExecuteNonQuery Method will return 0 or 1.
    bool result = Convert.ToBool(cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery());

   If insert is succsessful, you can try to execute the second query.
   if(result)
    {  
      If doesn't work, you should check your "Some Code" to be sure if you assign the the right parameters. 
      //Some Code
      cmd1.CommandText = cmdString2;
      cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
  }
 }
```

Comment: it return 1 i checked it

Comment: i post it but i don't think it will help

Comment: *md1.ExecuteNonQuery()* this returns the number of rows affected! Not `0` or `1`

Comment: Yes, in this case eighter 1 or 0.